# Unable to Build Qt Code on Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

Past few weeks I have been trying to setup Qt native build environment on **Raspberry Pi**.

I followed steps mentioned in [Native Build of Qt 5.4.1](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi).
Since I do not use USB Hard Disk, I omitted following steps:

1. Unpacking source to an external USB HDD
2. Increasing available RAM for concurrent compilation

Instead I extracted to moved to path: `cd ~/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1`

and for compilation I ran: `make 2>&1 | tee make.out`

I tried **Qt 5.4.1** to build on **Jessie** version of **Raspbian OS**, but it failed. I found similar error someone posted and tried to reply but no response at the end.
And now I tried Qt 5.4.1 on Wheezy version, and I get different error:

```
/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore//libJavaScriptCore.a: member /home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore//.obj/dfg/DFGThunks.o in archive is not an object
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.jsc:98: recipe for target '../../bin/jsc' failed
make[3]: *** [../../bin/jsc] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore'
Makefile.JavaScriptCore:126: recipe for target 'sub-jsc-pro-make_first-ordered' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-jsc-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit/Source/JavaScriptCore'
Makefile:93: recipe for target 'sub-Source-JavaScriptCore-JavaScriptCore-pro-make_first-ordered' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-Source-JavaScriptCore-JavaScriptCore-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit'
Makefile:485: recipe for target 'module-qtwebkit-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtwebkit-make_first] Error 2
```

Can someone tell me why this occurs? Is this Qt code issue? Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Try installing QT 4. I heard some issues were rising while installing QT 5.

Comment: @S.Iquebal: I need some qml features of Qt 5 to be used.